# Copying Strings Without Pesky Paragraph Markings

Tags: excel, vba, copy, string-formatting

Hi I'm a bit of a noob so please be gentle. I'm trying to make my life easier with a macro to copy a standard email with a single button. the email is being stored in a sheet with a whole list of email addresses so it would be convenient to just do it all in excel and add whatever codes I want.

My problem though is I keep getting these pesky paragraph marks at the end of a copy and I usually edit this out manually. It still happens when I do something like

```
range("L6").copy
```

so i tried stuff like

```
dim bla as string
bla = trim(range("L6").value)
bla.copy
```

but I'm finding this doesn't work. I even tried

```
left(range("L6").copy,len(range("L6").copy)-1).copy
```

but this doesnt work either.

a bit of background for those who care: I have a vendor list with all my vendor information including their email address for bank transfer advisories. in cell "L6" I have a multi-line message that I want to use that reads

Good Morning:

Please find attached copy of bank transfer payment.

Regards,

the message may change so the macro should target this cell. these pesky spaces are so annoying. I add more stuff to the email so its a nuisance to keep copying my standard email message. I even tried looking through the advanced settings of excel - no luck. Im not sure but I think the root of the problem is that the end comma is adding an additional paragraph space at the end of my highlighted text. Any help would be much appreciated. See screenshot for more detail. Thanks

[image: screenshot]

ps. dont know if im using the right tags for best response

Comment: try this `Selection.Find.Text = "^p".Replacement.Text = " "`

Comment: if this don't work try this `dim cleardata = Replace(Selection.Text, ChrW$(244), " ")`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you supply. But it **IS** the case that the copy process does **NOT** add a `paragraph space` at the end, whether or not there is a comma present. Suggest you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Possibly if you uploaded a worksheet that demonstrates the problem, someone could be of more help.

Comment: i noticed it only happens when there are multiple lines in one cell; after pasting the cursor jumps to the next line adding an extra paragraph space. alternatively, perhaps I could tackle the problem differently if I had each line in its own cell, how would I structure a multi-line copy? eg. how do i turn bla bla bla into bla [enter] bla [enter] bla? not exerianced enough but when i do range("a1"a3").copy it then pastes as a table. how would i keep it as a string

Comment: The issue is with `ms outlook` and how it handles data from Excel. Look into the different `paste-special` options, and also the advanced editing options within Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Strange. So those extra spaces stopped happening. literally, it was a matter of restarting the computer. Why? How? idk I blame Microsoft. this whole ordeal was quite a disappointment.

[image]

Comment: they are randomly back :( im realizing it has nothing to do with the vba. any time i copy even a one liner from excel an paste it into an outlook email it adds an extra paragraph space :(

Answer (score 0):

Ben,

Thanks for the update. Please refer to the following screenshot:

[image: Spaces]

As you can see when you select all (CTRL + A), there is always a gap shown at the end of each line.

1. there are no spaces, gaps in the text but small one at selection.
2. there is a space on 3rd line, resulting in a wider gap at selection.
3. There is a pipe on 3rd line, resulting in a wider gap at selection.

I do not think this translates in spaces during a copy (I did not encounter that issue copying and pasting from Excel to Outlook).

Good day,

Jonathan.

Comment: sure, please see my latest edit with a screenshot. I hope this better explains myself,
Cheers,-Ben